# Multiple Image Upload to Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i am trying to upload multiple files to spring boot server from angular 4 front end.

```
  selectedFile : File []  = [];
  filesToUpload: File[] = [];
  selectedFileNames: string[] = [];

  readURL(fileInput) {
    // this.detectFiles(fileInput);
    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++)
    {
        this.selectedFile.push(fileInput.target.files[i]);
    }
    console.log(this.selectedFile)
}

onUpload2(){
    const fd = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.filesToUpload.length; i++){
      fd.append('fileseee',this.selectedFile[i],this.selectedFile[i].name);
    }

    this.questionService.uploadImages(fd).
    subscribe( 
      (data: any) => {
           }
         )
   }



uploadImages(fda){
  console.log(fda);
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/imageUpload112",fda)
  .map((res : Response) => res);
}
```

the back end spring boot code works fine with postman.
the error showing is  "Request processing failed; nested exception is

[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause"

Comment: Can you please add the `uploadImages` function as well?

Comment: uploadImages(fda){
      console.log(fda);
      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+"/imageUpload112",fda)
      .map((res : Response) => res);
    }

Comment: Make sure in your request header the content type is for multipart data(Content-Type: multipart/form-data;).

Comment: i think this way i dont need to use Content-Type: multipart/form-data :/